# How to display current time on text label?

Tags: swift

I have just started with Swift and I am developing one simple application where I want to display a current time on display with text label.

Can any one please help me about that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a date formatter to format the date.

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .MediumStyle

var timeString = "The time is: \(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()))"
```

Set `timeString` to your label's `text` property. Run it on an `NSTimer` to keep it up to date.

Answer (score 14):

Display Live Time/Date in labels.

```
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!

var timer = Timer()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dateLabel.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .long, timeStyle: .none)
    timeLabel.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .short)
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector:#selector(self.tick) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func tick() {
    dateLabel.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .long, timeStyle: .none)
    timeLabel.text = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .none, timeStyle: .short)
}
```

Comment: This looks way more complicated than the accepted answer. If you answer an already answered question you should provide information on why your solution is necessary.

Comment: The user asked how to display the current time in a text label. The accepted answer only shows the time that the app is opened. My solution displays the current time/date when the app is opened and as the app is running and updates automatically.

Comment: The user even commented on the accepted answer that its working. This means your answer is also wrong (not what the user wanted). See the other late answers how to do it right, they posted a solution on how do do the same with a new version of swift.

Comment: This is what I needed to hear. I would disagree with Pinkie Swirl. Keep this around, it helps

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4:**

```
    var currentDateTime = Date()

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium

    yourLabel.text = "\(dateFormatter.string(from: currentDateTime))"
```

Answer (score 6):

### Swift 3.0

#### Method 1  (Using date formatter)

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .medium

let timeString = "The time is: \(dateFormatter.string(from: Date() as Date))"

label.text = String(timeString)
```

#### Method 2 (Get hour,minute,second seperately)

```
let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
let minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
let seconds = calendar.component(.second, from: date)

label1.text = String(hour) + ":" + String(minute) + ":" + String(seconds)
label2.text = String(day) + ":" + String(month) + ":" + String(year)
```